# an implicit solution is valid to show that the solution exists??

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

let us suppose we have a differential equation

$$ \frac{d^{2}y(x)}{dx^{2}}+F(y(x), y')=0 $$

for a knownn function $ F(x) $ which

assume we know that the INVERSE of the solution is

$$ y^{-1}(x)=x+g(x) $$

however $ g(x) $ is a very complicate function, sometimes $ g'(x) >0 $ and other times $ g(x) <0 $

so we do not know an ANALYTIC exact equation

my question is , from the very RIGOROUS mathematic is my solution (1) valid or i should prove that at least the inverse function theorem holds on a certain interval $ (a,b) $ what happens if the inverse function theorem does not hold??

assume also we can NOT use 'Lagrange theorem' to invert the function as a Taylor prower series because the function $ g(x) $ may not be differentiable on certain points or it may be piecewise differentiable

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the situation? You claim that for any or some solution $y=\phi(x)$ the inverse function has the form $x=\phi^{-1}(y)=y+g(y)$? And that you now want to solve this for $y$?

Comment: i have said that the solution to a certain differential equation $ y^{-1}(x)=x+g(X) $ but g(x) is known the unknon is $ y(x) $

Comment: But could you please explain the construct $y^{-1}(x)$? The inverse functional relation to $y(x)$ I would expect as $x(y)$.

Comment: wel if you lik put $ y^{-1}(x)=x(y)$ but i have always written this way with the minus 1

Comment: Your notation would be right if the context were just the inverse of a function. But here we have the additional context of the solution of a differential equation where the letters $x$ and $y$ have a more strictly defined meaning. $$x(s)=y^{-1}(s)=s+g(s)$$ would again do justice to this extended context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume from the form of the splitting that $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=0$ or more generally that $g(s)=\mathcal o(s)$?
$$ 
x=y+g(y)
$$
is invertible on a neighborhood of $0$ if one assumes that $g$ is Lipschitz with constant $L<1$ on a ball $B(0,R)$. Because then you can consider the iteration
$$
y_0=x, \quad y_{n+1}=x-g(y_n)
$$
which is contractive and a self-map of $B(0,R)$ for $x\in B(0,r)$ with $r=(1-L)R$ because of
$$
\|y_{n+1}\|\le \|x\|+L\|y_n\|\le r+LR\le R.
$$
So one gets an inverse map $y=y(x):B(0,r)\to B(0,R)$ which is Lipschitz as well with constant $\frac1{1-L}$

---

So you will have to prove that either $g(s)=\mathcal O(s^2)$ or that $|g'(s)|\le L<1$ for $s\approx 0$ or something similar that amounts to the above assumptions.